# remove property from nested json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array like this:

```
[{
    "name": "1392",
    "data": [{
        "saat2": 46.5,
        "maah2": "01",
        "saal2": 1392
    }, {
        "saat2": 114.06,
        "maah2": "02",
        "saal2": 1392
    }, {
        "saat2": 134.03,
        "maah2": "03",
        "saal2": 1392
    }, {
        "saat2": 137.18,
        "maah2": "04",
        "saal2": 1392
    }, {
        "saat2": 170.34,
        "maah2": "05",
        "saal2": 1392
    }, {
        "saat2": 179.91,
        "maah2": "06",
        "saal2": 1392
    }, {
        "saat2": 192.8,
        "maah2": "07",
        "saal2": 1392
    }, {
        "saat2": 189.11,
        "maah2": "08",
        "saal2": 1392
    }, {
        "saat2": 191.91,
        "maah2": "09",
        "saal2": 1392
    }, {
        "saat2": 225.07,
        "maah2": "10",
        "saal2": 1392
    }, {
        "saat2": 200.7,
        "maah2": "11",
        "saal2": 1392
    }, {
        "saat2": 209.34,
        "maah2": "12",
        "saal2": 1392
    }]
}, {
    "name": "1393",
    "data": [{
        "saat2": 130.97,
        "maah2": "۰۱",
        "saal2": 1393
    }, {
        "saat2": 185.17,
        "maah2": "۰۲",
        "saal2": 1393
    }, {
        "saat2": 92.74,
        "maah2": "۰۳",
        "saal2": 1393
    }, {
        "saat2": 112.7,
        "maah2": "۰۴",
        "saal2": 1393
    }, {
        "saat2": 96.5,
        "maah2": "۰۵",
        "saal2": 1393
    }, {
        "saat2": 91.14,
        "maah2": "۰۶",
        "saal2": 1393
    }, {
        "saat2": 65.67,
        "maah2": "۰۷",
        "saal2": 1393
    }, {
        "saat2": 71.23,
        "maah2": "۰۸",
        "saal2": 1393
    }, {
        "saat2": 104.71,
        "maah2": "۰۹",
        "saal2": 1393
    }, {
        "saat2": 105.18,
        "maah2": "۱۰",
        "saal2": 1393
    }, {
        "saat2": 93.24,
        "maah2": "۱۱",
        "saal2": 1393
    }, {
        "saat2": 98.95,
        "maah2": "۱۲",
        "saal2": 1393
    }]
}, {
    "name": "1394",
    "data": [{
        "saat2": 86.15,
        "maah2": "۰۱",
        "saal2": 1394
    }, {
        "saat2": 47.4,
        "maah2": "۰۲",
        "saal2": 1394
    }, {
        "saat2": 41.07,
        "maah2": "۰۳",
        "saal2": 1394
    }, {
        "saat2": 51.99,
        "maah2": "۰۴",
        "saal2": 1394
    }, {
        "saat2": 71.92,
        "maah2": "۰۵",
        "saal2": 1394
    }, {
        "saat2": 682.53,
        "maah2": "۰۶",
        "saal2": 1394
    }, {
        "saat2": 50.29,
        "maah2": "۰۷",
        "saal2": 1394
    }, {
        "saat2": 87.66,
        "maah2": "۰۸",
        "saal2": 1394
    }, {
        "saat2": 49.19,
        "maah2": "۰۹",
        "saal2": 1394
    }, {
        "saat2": 60.7,
        "maah2": "۱۰",
        "saal2": 1394
    }, {
        "saat2": 69.21,
        "maah2": "۱۱",
        "saal2": 1394
    }, {
        "saat2": 54.23,
        "maah2": "۱۲",
        "saal2": 1394
    }]
}, {
    "name": "1395",
    "data": [{
        "saat2": 42.86,
        "maah2": "01",
        "saal2": 1395
    }, {
        "saat2": 99.04,
        "maah2": "02",
        "saal2": 1395
    }, {
        "saat2": 51.4,
        "maah2": "۰۳",
        "saal2": 1395
    }, {
        "saat2": 29.83,
        "maah2": "۰۴",
        "saal2": 1395
    }, {
        "saat2": 68.83,
        "maah2": "۰۵",
        "saal2": 1395
    }, {
        "saat2": 68.18,
        "maah2": "۰۶",
        "saal2": 1395
    }, {
        "saat2": 65.34,
        "maah2": "۰۷",
        "saal2": 1395
    }, {
        "saat2": 61.82,
        "maah2": "۰۸",
        "saal2": 1395
    }, {
        "saat2": 82.15,
        "maah2": "۰۹",
        "saal2": 1395
    }, {
        "saat2": 129.64,
        "maah2": "۱۰",
        "saal2": 1395
    }, {
        "saat2": 116.69,
        "maah2": "۱۱",
        "saal2": 1395
    }, {
        "saat2": 117.1,
        "maah2": "۱۲",
        "saal2": 1395
    }]
}, {
    "name": "1396",
    "data": [{
        "saat2": 70.22,
        "maah2": "۰۱",
        "saal2": 1396
    }, {
        "saat2": 109.9,
        "maah2": "۰۲",
        "saal2": 1396
    }, {
        "saat2": 82.15,
        "maah2": "۰۳",
        "saal2": 1396
    }, {
        "saat2": 55.22,
        "maah2": "۰۴",
        "saal2": 1396
    }, {
        "saat2": 108.07,
        "maah2": "۰۵",
        "saal2": 1396
    }, {
        "saat2": 98.84,
        "maah2": "۰۶",
        "saal2": 1396
    }, {
        "saat2": 104.56,
        "maah2": "۰۷",
        "saal2": 1396
    }, {
        "saat2": 84.16,
        "maah2": "۰۸",
        "saal2": 1396
    }, {
        "saat2": 71.8,
        "maah2": "۰۹",
        "saal2": 1396
    }, {
        "saat2": 123.09,
        "maah2": "۱۰",
        "saal2": 1396
    }, {
        "saat2": 110.8,
        "maah2": "۱۱",
        "saal2": 1396
    }, {
        "saat2": 162.28,
        "maah2": "۱۲",
        "saal2": 1396
    }]
}, {
    "name": "1397",
    "data": [{
        "saat2": 59.22,
        "maah2": "01",
        "saal2": 1397
    }, {
        "saat2": 63.7,
        "maah2": "02",
        "saal2": 1397
    }, {
        "saat2": 70.21,
        "maah2": "03",
        "saal2": 1397
    }, {
        "saat2": 103.82,
        "maah2": "04",
        "saal2": 1397
    }, {
        "saat2": 113.22,
        "maah2": "05",
        "saal2": 1397
    }, {
        "saat2": 108.05,
        "maah2": "06",
        "saal2": 1397
    }, {
        "saat2": 114.69,
        "maah2": "07",
        "saal2": 1397
    }, {
        "saat2": 56.49,
        "maah2": "08",
        "saal2": 1397
    }, {
        "saat2": 97.72,
        "maah2": "09",
        "saal2": 1397
    }, {
        "saat2": 54.23,
        "maah2": "10",
        "saal2": 1397
    }, {
        "saat2": 22.18,
        "maah2": "11",
        "saal2": 1397
    }, {
        "saat2": 58.61,
        "maah2": "12",
        "saal2": 1397
    }]
}, {
    "name": "1398",
    "data": [{
        "saat2": 15.45,
        "maah2": "01",
        "saal2": 1398
    }, {
        "saat2": 38.06,
        "maah2": "02",
        "saal2": 1398
    }, {
        "saat2": 27.07,
        "maah2": "03",
        "saal2": 1398
    }, {
        "saat2": 0.33,
        "maah2": "10",
        "saal2": 1398
    }, {
        "saat2": 6.78,
        "maah2": "11",
        "saal2": 1398
    }, {
        "saat2": 8.78,
        "maah2": "12",
        "saal2": 1398
    }]
}, {
    "name": "1399",
    "data": [{
        "saat2": 63.08,
        "maah2": "02",
        "saal2": 1399
    }, {
        "saat2": 29.82,
        "maah2": "03",
        "saal2": 1399
    }, {
        "saat2": 61.58,
        "maah2": "04",
        "saal2": 1399
    }, {
        "saat2": 36.59,
        "maah2": "05",
        "saal2": 1399
    }, {
        "saat2": 33.02,
        "maah2": "06",
        "saal2": 1399
    }, {
        "saat2": 58.86,
        "maah2": "07",
        "saal2": 1399
    }, {
        "saat2": 59.72,
        "maah2": "08",
        "saal2": 1399
    }, {
        "saat2": 33.99,
        "maah2": "09",
        "saal2": 1399
    }, {
        "saat2": 59.6,
        "maah2": "10",
        "saal2": 1399
    }, {
        "saat2": 70.01,
        "maah2": "11",
        "saal2": 1399
    }, {
        "saat2": 81.66,
        "maah2": "12",
        "saal2": 1399
    }]
}, {
    "name": "1400",
    "data": [{
        "saat2": 132.16,
        "maah2": "01",
        "saal2": 1400
    }, {
        "saat2": 61.96,
        "maah2": "02",
        "saal2": 1400
    }, {
        "saat2": 71.14,
        "maah2": "03",
        "saal2": 1400
    }, {
        "saat2": 54.3,
        "maah2": "04",
        "saal2": 1400
    }, {
        "saat2": 52.79,
        "maah2": "05",
        "saal2": 1400
    }, {
        "saat2": 37.68,
        "maah2": "06",
        "saal2": 1400
    }]
}]
```

I want to remove saal2 and it's value.I tried map and reduce but got no success.

Comment: could you add your code too?

Comment: My code is not working.

Comment: this is unclear : map and reduce create a new array or object. You want to just update your existing object with deleting some properties ?

Comment: yes I understand but only then we'd be able to suggest improvements to help you out!

Comment: yes I want some code to get rid of nested property saal2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this, iterating over the starting array and deleting the nested property for each data object

```js
start.forEach(se => se.data.forEach(a => delete a.saal2))
```

```js
const start = [{
  "name": "1392",
  "data": [{
    "saat2": 46.5,
    "maah2": "01",
    "saal2": 1392
  }, {
    "saat2": 114.06,
    "maah2": "02",
    "saal2": 1392
  }, {
    "saat2": 134.03,
    "maah2": "03",
    "saal2": 1392
  }, {
    "saat2": 137.18,
    "maah2": "04",
    "saal2": 1392
  }, {
    "saat2": 170.34,
    "maah2": "05",
    "saal2": 1392
  }, {
    "saat2": 179.91,
    "maah2": "06",
    "saal2": 1392
  }, {
    "saat2": 192.8,
    "maah2": "07",
    "saal2": 1392
  }, {
    "saat2": 189.11,
    "maah2": "08",
    "saal2": 1392
  }, {
    "saat2": 191.91,
    "maah2": "09",
    "saal2": 1392
  }, {
    "saat2": 225.07,
    "maah2": "10",
    "saal2": 1392
  }, {
    "saat2": 200.7,
    "maah2": "11",
    "saal2": 1392
  }, {
    "saat2": 209.34,
    "maah2": "12",
    "saal2": 1392
  }]
}, {
  "name": "1393",
  "data": [{
    "saat2": 130.97,
    "maah2": "۰۱",
    "saal2": 1393
  }, {
    "saat2": 185.17,
    "maah2": "۰۲",
    "saal2": 1393
  }, {
    "saat2": 92.74,
    "maah2": "۰۳",
    "saal2": 1393
  }, {
    "saat2": 112.7,
    "maah2": "۰۴",
    "saal2": 1393
  }, {
    "saat2": 96.5,
    "maah2": "۰۵",
    "saal2": 1393
  }, {
    "saat2": 91.14,
    "maah2": "۰۶",
    "saal2": 1393
  }, {
    "saat2": 65.67,
    "maah2": "۰۷",
    "saal2": 1393
  }, {
    "saat2": 71.23,
    "maah2": "۰۸",
    "saal2": 1393
  }, {
    "saat2": 104.71,
    "maah2": "۰۹",
    "saal2": 1393
  }, {
    "saat2": 105.18,
    "maah2": "۱۰",
    "saal2": 1393
  }, {
    "saat2": 93.24,
    "maah2": "۱۱",
    "saal2": 1393
  }, {
    "saat2": 98.95,
    "maah2": "۱۲",
    "saal2": 1393
  }]
}, {
  "name": "1394",
  "data": [{
    "saat2": 86.15,
    "maah2": "۰۱",
    "saal2": 1394
  }, {
    "saat2": 47.4,
    "maah2": "۰۲",
    "saal2": 1394
  }, {
    "saat2": 41.07,
    "maah2": "۰۳",
    "saal2": 1394
  }, {
    "saat2": 51.99,
    "maah2": "۰۴",
    "saal2": 1394
  }, {
    "saat2": 71.92,
    "maah2": "۰۵",
    "saal2": 1394
  }, {
    "saat2": 682.53,
    "maah2": "۰۶",
    "saal2": 1394
  }, {
    "saat2": 50.29,
    "maah2": "۰۷",
    "saal2": 1394
  }, {
    "saat2": 87.66,
    "maah2": "۰۸",
    "saal2": 1394
  }, {
    "saat2": 49.19,
    "maah2": "۰۹",
    "saal2": 1394
  }, {
    "saat2": 60.7,
    "maah2": "۱۰",
    "saal2": 1394
  }, {
    "saat2": 69.21,
    "maah2": "۱۱",
    "saal2": 1394
  }, {
    "saat2": 54.23,
    "maah2": "۱۲",
    "saal2": 1394
  }]
}, {
  "name": "1395",
  "data": [{
    "saat2": 42.86,
    "maah2": "01",
    "saal2": 1395
  }, {
    "saat2": 99.04,
    "maah2": "02",
    "saal2": 1395
  }, {
    "saat2": 51.4,
    "maah2": "۰۳",
    "saal2": 1395
  }, {
    "saat2": 29.83,
    "maah2": "۰۴",
    "saal2": 1395
  }, {
    "saat2": 68.83,
    "maah2": "۰۵",
    "saal2": 1395
  }, {
    "saat2": 68.18,
    "maah2": "۰۶",
    "saal2": 1395
  }, {
    "saat2": 65.34,
    "maah2": "۰۷",
    "saal2": 1395
  }, {
    "saat2": 61.82,
    "maah2": "۰۸",
    "saal2": 1395
  }, {
    "saat2": 82.15,
    "maah2": "۰۹",
    "saal2": 1395
  }, {
    "saat2": 129.64,
    "maah2": "۱۰",
    "saal2": 1395
  }, {
    "saat2": 116.69,
    "maah2": "۱۱",
    "saal2": 1395
  }, {
    "saat2": 117.1,
    "maah2": "۱۲",
    "saal2": 1395
  }]
}, {
  "name": "1396",
  "data": [{
    "saat2": 70.22,
    "maah2": "۰۱",
    "saal2": 1396
  }, {
    "saat2": 109.9,
    "maah2": "۰۲",
    "saal2": 1396
  }, {
    "saat2": 82.15,
    "maah2": "۰۳",
    "saal2": 1396
  }, {
    "saat2": 55.22,
    "maah2": "۰۴",
    "saal2": 1396
  }, {
    "saat2": 108.07,
    "maah2": "۰۵",
    "saal2": 1396
  }, {
    "saat2": 98.84,
    "maah2": "۰۶",
    "saal2": 1396
  }, {
    "saat2": 104.56,
    "maah2": "۰۷",
    "saal2": 1396
  }, {
    "saat2": 84.16,
    "maah2": "۰۸",
    "saal2": 1396
  }, {
    "saat2": 71.8,
    "maah2": "۰۹",
    "saal2": 1396
  }, {
    "saat2": 123.09,
    "maah2": "۱۰",
    "saal2": 1396
  }, {
    "saat2": 110.8,
    "maah2": "۱۱",
    "saal2": 1396
  }, {
    "saat2": 162.28,
    "maah2": "۱۲",
    "saal2": 1396
  }]
}, {
  "name": "1397",
  "data": [{
    "saat2": 59.22,
    "maah2": "01",
    "saal2": 1397
  }, {
    "saat2": 63.7,
    "maah2": "02",
    "saal2": 1397
  }, {
    "saat2": 70.21,
    "maah2": "03",
    "saal2": 1397
  }, {
    "saat2": 103.82,
    "maah2": "04",
    "saal2": 1397
  }, {
    "saat2": 113.22,
    "maah2": "05",
    "saal2": 1397
  }, {
    "saat2": 108.05,
    "maah2": "06",
    "saal2": 1397
  }, {
    "saat2": 114.69,
    "maah2": "07",
    "saal2": 1397
  }, {
    "saat2": 56.49,
    "maah2": "08",
    "saal2": 1397
  }, {
    "saat2": 97.72,
    "maah2": "09",
    "saal2": 1397
  }, {
    "saat2": 54.23,
    "maah2": "10",
    "saal2": 1397
  }, {
    "saat2": 22.18,
    "maah2": "11",
    "saal2": 1397
  }, {
    "saat2": 58.61,
    "maah2": "12",
    "saal2": 1397
  }]
}, {
  "name": "1398",
  "data": [{
    "saat2": 15.45,
    "maah2": "01",
    "saal2": 1398
  }, {
    "saat2": 38.06,
    "maah2": "02",
    "saal2": 1398
  }, {
    "saat2": 27.07,
    "maah2": "03",
    "saal2": 1398
  }, {
    "saat2": 0.33,
    "maah2": "10",
    "saal2": 1398
  }, {
    "saat2": 6.78,
    "maah2": "11",
    "saal2": 1398
  }, {
    "saat2": 8.78,
    "maah2": "12",
    "saal2": 1398
  }]
}, {
  "name": "1399",
  "data": [{
    "saat2": 63.08,
    "maah2": "02",
    "saal2": 1399
  }, {
    "saat2": 29.82,
    "maah2": "03",
    "saal2": 1399
  }, {
    "saat2": 61.58,
    "maah2": "04",
    "saal2": 1399
  }, {
    "saat2": 36.59,
    "maah2": "05",
    "saal2": 1399
  }, {
    "saat2": 33.02,
    "maah2": "06",
    "saal2": 1399
  }, {
    "saat2": 58.86,
    "maah2": "07",
    "saal2": 1399
  }, {
    "saat2": 59.72,
    "maah2": "08",
    "saal2": 1399
  }, {
    "saat2": 33.99,
    "maah2": "09",
    "saal2": 1399
  }, {
    "saat2": 59.6,
    "maah2": "10",
    "saal2": 1399
  }, {
    "saat2": 70.01,
    "maah2": "11",
    "saal2": 1399
  }, {
    "saat2": 81.66,
    "maah2": "12",
    "saal2": 1399
  }]
}, {
  "name": "1400",
  "data": [{
    "saat2": 132.16,
    "maah2": "01",
    "saal2": 1400
  }, {
    "saat2": 61.96,
    "maah2": "02",
    "saal2": 1400
  }, {
    "saat2": 71.14,
    "maah2": "03",
    "saal2": 1400
  }, {
    "saat2": 54.3,
    "maah2": "04",
    "saal2": 1400
  }, {
    "saat2": 52.79,
    "maah2": "05",
    "saal2": 1400
  }, {
    "saat2": 37.68,
    "maah2": "06",
    "saal2": 1400
  }]
}];

start.forEach(se => se.data.forEach(a => delete a.saal2))

console.log(start)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this recursively, creating a function like `removeProperty` and traversing the input. If a key matches the property to remove, we'll use `delete` to remove it.

If a child property is an `object` we'll apply the removeProperty to that value and so on.

```js
let input = [{ "name": "1392", "data": [{ "saat2": 46.5, "maah2": "01", "saal2": 1392 }, { "saat2": 114.06, "maah2": "02", "saal2": 1392 }, { "saat2": 134.03, "maah2": "03", "saal2": 1392 }, { "saat2": 137.18, "maah2": "04", "saal2": 1392 }, { "saat2": 170.34, "maah2": "05", "saal2": 1392 }, { "saat2": 179.91, "maah2": "06", "saal2": 1392 }, { "saat2": 192.8, "maah2": "07", "saal2": 1392 }, { "saat2": 189.11, "maah2": "08", "saal2": 1392 }, { "saat2": 191.91, "maah2": "09", "saal2": 1392 }, { "saat2": 225.07, "maah2": "10", "saal2": 1392 }, { "saat2": 200.7, "maah2": "11", "saal2": 1392 }, { "saat2": 209.34, "maah2": "12", "saal2": 1392 }] }, { "name": "1393", "data": [{ "saat2": 130.97, "maah2": "۰۱", "saal2": 1393 }, { "saat2": 185.17, "maah2": "۰۲", "saal2": 1393 }, { "saat2": 92.74, "maah2": "۰۳", "saal2": 1393 }, { "saat2": 112.7, "maah2": "۰۴", "saal2": 1393 }, { "saat2": 96.5, "maah2": "۰۵", "saal2": 1393 }, { "saat2": 91.14, "maah2": "۰۶", "saal2": 1393 }, { "saat2": 65.67, "maah2": "۰۷", "saal2": 1393 }, { "saat2": 71.23, "maah2": "۰۸", "saal2": 1393 }, { "saat2": 104.71, "maah2": "۰۹", "saal2": 1393 }, { "saat2": 105.18, "maah2": "۱۰", "saal2": 1393 }, { "saat2": 93.24, "maah2": "۱۱", "saal2": 1393 }, { "saat2": 98.95, "maah2": "۱۲", "saal2": 1393 }] }, { "name": "1394", "data": [{ "saat2": 86.15, "maah2": "۰۱", "saal2": 1394 }, { "saat2": 47.4, "maah2": "۰۲", "saal2": 1394 }, { "saat2": 41.07, "maah2": "۰۳", "saal2": 1394 }, { "saat2": 51.99, "maah2": "۰۴", "saal2": 1394 }, { "saat2": 71.92, "maah2": "۰۵", "saal2": 1394 }, { "saat2": 682.53, "maah2": "۰۶", "saal2": 1394 }, { "saat2": 50.29, "maah2": "۰۷", "saal2": 1394 }, { "saat2": 87.66, "maah2": "۰۸", "saal2": 1394 }, { "saat2": 49.19, "maah2": "۰۹", "saal2": 1394 }, { "saat2": 60.7, "maah2": "۱۰", "saal2": 1394 }, { "saat2": 69.21, "maah2": "۱۱", "saal2": 1394 }, { "saat2": 54.23, "maah2": "۱۲", "saal2": 1394 }] }, { "name": "1395", "data": [{ "saat2": 42.86, "maah2": "01", "saal2": 1395 }, { "saat2": 99.04, "maah2": "02", "saal2": 1395 }, { "saat2": 51.4, "maah2": "۰۳", "saal2": 1395 }, { "saat2": 29.83, "maah2": "۰۴", "saal2": 1395 }, { "saat2": 68.83, "maah2": "۰۵", "saal2": 1395 }, { "saat2": 68.18, "maah2": "۰۶", "saal2": 1395 }, { "saat2": 65.34, "maah2": "۰۷", "saal2": 1395 }, { "saat2": 61.82, "maah2": "۰۸", "saal2": 1395 }, { "saat2": 82.15, "maah2": "۰۹", "saal2": 1395 }, { "saat2": 129.64, "maah2": "۱۰", "saal2": 1395 }, { "saat2": 116.69, "maah2": "۱۱", "saal2": 1395 }, { "saat2": 117.1, "maah2": "۱۲", "saal2": 1395 }] }, { "name": "1396", "data": [{ "saat2": 70.22, "maah2": "۰۱", "saal2": 1396 }, { "saat2": 109.9, "maah2": "۰۲", "saal2": 1396 }, { "saat2": 82.15, "maah2": "۰۳", "saal2": 1396 }, { "saat2": 55.22, "maah2": "۰۴", "saal2": 1396 }, { "saat2": 108.07, "maah2": "۰۵", "saal2": 1396 }, { "saat2": 98.84, "maah2": "۰۶", "saal2": 1396 }, { "saat2": 104.56, "maah2": "۰۷", "saal2": 1396 }, { "saat2": 84.16, "maah2": "۰۸", "saal2": 1396 }, { "saat2": 71.8, "maah2": "۰۹", "saal2": 1396 }, { "saat2": 123.09, "maah2": "۱۰", "saal2": 1396 }, { "saat2": 110.8, "maah2": "۱۱", "saal2": 1396 }, { "saat2": 162.28, "maah2": "۱۲", "saal2": 1396 }] }, { "name": "1397", "data": [{ "saat2": 59.22, "maah2": "01", "saal2": 1397 }, { "saat2": 63.7, "maah2": "02", "saal2": 1397 }, { "saat2": 70.21, "maah2": "03", "saal2": 1397 }, { "saat2": 103.82, "maah2": "04", "saal2": 1397 }, { "saat2": 113.22, "maah2": "05", "saal2": 1397 }, { "saat2": 108.05, "maah2": "06", "saal2": 1397 }, { "saat2": 114.69, "maah2": "07", "saal2": 1397 }, { "saat2": 56.49, "maah2": "08", "saal2": 1397 }, { "saat2": 97.72, "maah2": "09", "saal2": 1397 }, { "saat2": 54.23, "maah2": "10", "saal2": 1397 }, { "saat2": 22.18, "maah2": "11", "saal2": 1397 }, { "saat2": 58.61, "maah2": "12", "saal2": 1397 }] }, { "name": "1398", "data": [{ "saat2": 15.45, "maah2": "01", "saal2": 1398 }, { "saat2": 38.06, "maah2": "02", "saal2": 1398 }, { "saat2": 27.07, "maah2": "03", "saal2": 1398 }, { "saat2": 0.33, "maah2": "10", "saal2": 1398 }, { "saat2": 6.78, "maah2": "11", "saal2": 1398 }, { "saat2": 8.78, "maah2": "12", "saal2": 1398 }] }, { "name": "1399", "data": [{ "saat2": 63.08, "maah2": "02", "saal2": 1399 }, { "saat2": 29.82, "maah2": "03", "saal2": 1399 }, { "saat2": 61.58, "maah2": "04", "saal2": 1399 }, { "saat2": 36.59, "maah2": "05", "saal2": 1399 }, { "saat2": 33.02, "maah2": "06", "saal2": 1399 }, { "saat2": 58.86, "maah2": "07", "saal2": 1399 }, { "saat2": 59.72, "maah2": "08", "saal2": 1399 }, { "saat2": 33.99, "maah2": "09", "saal2": 1399 }, { "saat2": 59.6, "maah2": "10", "saal2": 1399 }, { "saat2": 70.01, "maah2": "11", "saal2": 1399 }, { "saat2": 81.66, "maah2": "12", "saal2": 1399 }] }, { "name": "1400", "data": [{ "saat2": 132.16, "maah2": "01", "saal2": 1400 }, { "saat2": 61.96, "maah2": "02", "saal2": 1400 }, { "saat2": 71.14, "maah2": "03", "saal2": 1400 }, { "saat2": 54.3, "maah2": "04", "saal2": 1400 }, { "saat2": 52.79, "maah2": "05", "saal2": 1400 }, { "saat2": 37.68, "maah2": "06", "saal2": 1400 }] }]

function removeProperty(obj, propertyToRemove) {
    for(let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        if (propertyToRemove === key) { 
            delete obj[key];
        } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            removeProperty(obj[key], propertyToRemove)
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

removeProperty(input, 'saal2');
console.log('Result:', input);
```

Answer (score 1):

To edit the existing array, we can use

```js
data.forEach(a => a.data.forEach(d => delete d['saal2']));
```

Since the objects are in a deeper list, we'll need 2 `forEach` to reach the desired key. Then use the `delete` keyword.

```js
let data = [{"name": "1392", "data": [{"saat2": 46.5, "maah2": "01", "saal2": 1392 }, {"saat2": 114.06, "maah2": "02", "saal2": 1392 }, {"saat2": 134.03, "maah2": "03", "saal2": 1392 }, {"saat2": 137.18, "maah2": "04", "saal2": 1392 }, {"saat2": 170.34, "maah2": "05", "saal2": 1392 }, {"saat2": 179.91, "maah2": "06", "saal2": 1392 }, {"saat2": 192.8, "maah2": "07", "saal2": 1392 }, {"saat2": 189.11, "maah2": "08", "saal2": 1392 }, {"saat2": 191.91, "maah2": "09", "saal2": 1392 }, {"saat2": 225.07, "maah2": "10", "saal2": 1392 }, {"saat2": 200.7, "maah2": "11", "saal2": 1392 }, {"saat2": 209.34, "maah2": "12", "saal2": 1392 }] }, {"name": "1393", "data": [{"saat2": 130.97, "maah2": "۰۱", "saal2": 1393 }, {"saat2": 185.17, "maah2": "۰۲", "saal2": 1393 }, {"saat2": 92.74, "maah2": "۰۳", "saal2": 1393 }, {"saat2": 112.7, "maah2": "۰۴", "saal2": 1393 }, {"saat2": 96.5, "maah2": "۰۵", "saal2": 1393 }, {"saat2": 91.14, "maah2": "۰۶", "saal2": 1393 }, {"saat2": 65.67, "maah2": "۰۷", "saal2": 1393 }, {"saat2": 71.23, "maah2": "۰۸", "saal2": 1393 }, {"saat2": 104.71, "maah2": "۰۹", "saal2": 1393 }, {"saat2": 105.18, "maah2": "۱۰", "saal2": 1393 }, {"saat2": 93.24, "maah2": "۱۱", "saal2": 1393 }, {"saat2": 98.95, "maah2": "۱۲", "saal2": 1393 }] }, {"name": "1394", "data": [{"saat2": 86.15, "maah2": "۰۱", "saal2": 1394 }, {"saat2": 47.4, "maah2": "۰۲", "saal2": 1394 }, {"saat2": 41.07, "maah2": "۰۳", "saal2": 1394 }, {"saat2": 51.99, "maah2": "۰۴", "saal2": 1394 }, {"saat2": 71.92, "maah2": "۰۵", "saal2": 1394 }, {"saat2": 682.53, "maah2": "۰۶", "saal2": 1394 }, {"saat2": 50.29, "maah2": "۰۷", "saal2": 1394 }, {"saat2": 87.66, "maah2": "۰۸", "saal2": 1394 }, {"saat2": 49.19, "maah2": "۰۹", "saal2": 1394 }, {"saat2": 60.7, "maah2": "۱۰", "saal2": 1394 }, {"saat2": 69.21, "maah2": "۱۱", "saal2": 1394 }, {"saat2": 54.23, "maah2": "۱۲", "saal2": 1394 }] }, {"name": "1395", "data": [{"saat2": 42.86, "maah2": "01", "saal2": 1395 }, {"saat2": 99.04, "maah2": "02", "saal2": 1395 }, {"saat2": 51.4, "maah2": "۰۳", "saal2": 1395 }, {"saat2": 29.83, "maah2": "۰۴", "saal2": 1395 }, {"saat2": 68.83, "maah2": "۰۵", "saal2": 1395 }, {"saat2": 68.18, "maah2": "۰۶", "saal2": 1395 }, {"saat2": 65.34, "maah2": "۰۷", "saal2": 1395 }, {"saat2": 61.82, "maah2": "۰۸", "saal2": 1395 }, {"saat2": 82.15, "maah2": "۰۹", "saal2": 1395 }, {"saat2": 129.64, "maah2": "۱۰", "saal2": 1395 }, {"saat2": 116.69, "maah2": "۱۱", "saal2": 1395 }, {"saat2": 117.1, "maah2": "۱۲", "saal2": 1395 }] }, {"name": "1396", "data": [{"saat2": 70.22, "maah2": "۰۱", "saal2": 1396 }, {"saat2": 109.9, "maah2": "۰۲", "saal2": 1396 }, {"saat2": 82.15, "maah2": "۰۳", "saal2": 1396 }, {"saat2": 55.22, "maah2": "۰۴", "saal2": 1396 }, {"saat2": 108.07, "maah2": "۰۵", "saal2": 1396 }, {"saat2": 98.84, "maah2": "۰۶", "saal2": 1396 }, {"saat2": 104.56, "maah2": "۰۷", "saal2": 1396 }, {"saat2": 84.16, "maah2": "۰۸", "saal2": 1396 }, {"saat2": 71.8, "maah2": "۰۹", "saal2": 1396 }, {"saat2": 123.09, "maah2": "۱۰", "saal2": 1396 }, {"saat2": 110.8, "maah2": "۱۱", "saal2": 1396 }, {"saat2": 162.28, "maah2": "۱۲", "saal2": 1396 }] }, {"name": "1397", "data": [{"saat2": 59.22, "maah2": "01", "saal2": 1397 }, {"saat2": 63.7, "maah2": "02", "saal2": 1397 }, {"saat2": 70.21, "maah2": "03", "saal2": 1397 }, {"saat2": 103.82, "maah2": "04", "saal2": 1397 }, {"saat2": 113.22, "maah2": "05", "saal2": 1397 }, {"saat2": 108.05, "maah2": "06", "saal2": 1397 }, {"saat2": 114.69, "maah2": "07", "saal2": 1397 }, {"saat2": 56.49, "maah2": "08", "saal2": 1397 }, {"saat2": 97.72, "maah2": "09", "saal2": 1397 }, {"saat2": 54.23, "maah2": "10", "saal2": 1397 }, {"saat2": 22.18, "maah2": "11", "saal2": 1397 }, {"saat2": 58.61, "maah2": "12", "saal2": 1397 }] }, {"name": "1398", "data": [{"saat2": 15.45, "maah2": "01", "saal2": 1398 }, {"saat2": 38.06, "maah2": "02", "saal2": 1398 }, {"saat2": 27.07, "maah2": "03", "saal2": 1398 }, {"saat2": 0.33, "maah2": "10", "saal2": 1398 }, {"saat2": 6.78, "maah2": "11", "saal2": 1398 }, {"saat2": 8.78, "maah2": "12", "saal2": 1398 }] }, {"name": "1399", "data": [{"saat2": 63.08, "maah2": "02", "saal2": 1399 }, {"saat2": 29.82, "maah2": "03", "saal2": 1399 }, {"saat2": 61.58, "maah2": "04", "saal2": 1399 }, {"saat2": 36.59, "maah2": "05", "saal2": 1399 }, {"saat2": 33.02, "maah2": "06", "saal2": 1399 }, {"saat2": 58.86, "maah2": "07", "saal2": 1399 }, {"saat2": 59.72, "maah2": "08", "saal2": 1399 }, {"saat2": 33.99, "maah2": "09", "saal2": 1399 }, {"saat2": 59.6, "maah2": "10", "saal2": 1399 }, {"saat2": 70.01, "maah2": "11", "saal2": 1399 }, {"saat2": 81.66, "maah2": "12", "saal2": 1399 }] }, {"name": "1400", "data": [{"saat2": 132.16, "maah2": "01", "saal2": 1400 }, {"saat2": 61.96, "maah2": "02", "saal2": 1400 }, {"saat2": 71.14, "maah2": "03", "saal2": 1400 }, {"saat2": 54.3, "maah2": "04", "saal2": 1400 }, {"saat2": 52.79, "maah2": "05", "saal2": 1400 }, {"saat2": 37.68, "maah2": "06", "saal2": 1400 }] }];

data.forEach(a => a.data.forEach(d => delete d['saal2']));
console.log(data);
```